# Product Quantity After Order Placement on Success Page

Tags: checkout, quantity

I want to get the item quantity which was before Placing the order. Like before I place an order, the product quantity was 10. I ordered products with quantity 2. But when I get the stock quantity on Success Page,I got 8. How to get that quantity which was before placing the order. I want to show backorder on success page. Like what was the item quantity at the order placement time.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below configuration.

1. `Go to admin > Stores > Configuratins > Catalog > InvaInventory > Stock Options > Decrease Stock When Order is Placed`
2. Please Choose **Decrease Stock When Order is Placed** field Option is **No**.
3. Click on **save** button and **cache flush** .

[image]